# Beginning with git - cloning from remote to local

Tags: git

I need to work with a git repo that was set up in a remote machine in my company to which I have access via ssh with my company's login. I can sudo on the remote machine.

After reading some git tutorial I see I should clone the repo locally and so I tried:

```
me$ git clone git://remote.company.com/git/tools/thing.git
Cloning into thing...
remote.company.com[0: 1.2.3.4]: errno=Connection refused
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)
me$ git clone http://remote.company.com/git/tools/thing.git
Cloning into thing...
fatal: http://remote.company.com/git/tools/thing.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

So I switched back to the remote machine and tried:

```
me@remote:/home/git/tools/thing.git$ git update-server-info
error: unable to update ./info/refs+
error: cannot open ./objects/info/packs+
me@remote:/home/git/tools/thing.git$ sudo git update-server-info
[sudo] password for me: 
me@remote:/home/git/tools/thing.git$
```

Not much success!
Am I doing something conceptually wrong in beginning to work with this repo? FYI, I was thinking to create an actual remote branch for some new functionalities and to work from there.

UPDATE 1:

```
me$ git clone ssh://git@remote.company.com/tools/thing.git
Cloning into thing...
fatal: '/tools/thing.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Tried the same thing without `git@`, with various permutations of folders and .git extensions. 
Nothing works.

UPDATE 2:

Ok, found it.. :) `git clone git@remote.company.com:tools/thing`

Comment: Have you tried: ``git clone ssh://remote.company.com/thing.git`` or with ``ssh://remote.company.com/tools/thing.git`` or the likes? If these don't work, ask the admin.

Comment: A typical setup has a git pseudo-user on the repository host with a clone URL of the form `ssh://git@remote.company.com/tools/thing.git`. Try that clone URL, but it is concerning that git does not appear to own the repo.

Comment: Thanks Greg and Jonas. Please check the update above!

Comment: Try ``ssh://…/home/git/tools/thing.git``

Comment: Ok, I think I got it! Thanks to all

Comment: @JoeSlav, can you post the solution as a separate answer and accept that. would be helpful for future searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is: `git clone git@remote.company.com:tools/thing`

Thanks to all!